# Can you encroach a person?

Tags: word-usage

Used in a sentence like this -

> Not to mention, the transit employee encroached the Mexican guy, as the Mexican guy is in retreat.

Sounds wrong to me. But is encroaching strictly incorrect when used like this when referring directly to a person instead of their personal space, authority etc?

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/PublicFreakout/comments/toy47y/chicago_transit_employee_pulls_gun_out_on/i2ahd0r/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a chat on Reddit, which should not be regarded as a source of reference-quality English. These are remarks made by anyone, not just fluent Standard English speakers, and often typed in haste without checking. There are a number of non-standard features: 'Not to mention,' at the beginning, and the mixture of tenses ('encroached' and 'is'). The use of 'encroached' about a person without a preposition ('on' or 'upon') and an object (such as 'the Mexican guy's personal space') is decidedly non-standard.

[image]

encroach

> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> **usually encroach on/upon**
>
> Intrude on (a person's territory, rights, personal life, etc.)
>
> ‘rather than encroach on his privacy she might have kept to her room’

[Encroach (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/encroach)

Answer (score -1):

By my interpretation, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/encroach) disagrees and allows this usage:

> If one thing encroaches on another, the first thing spreads or becomes stronger, and slowly begins to restrict the power, range, or effectiveness of the second thing.

The transit employee metaphorically *spread* by intimidating and getting closer to the Mexican person, and restricted their power. It's maybe a bit nonstandard (usually you would *encroach upon* some sort literal or metaphorical space), but I don't think it's strictly incorrect.

That said, *encroach* is generally intransitive and followed by *on*, *upon* or *in*. The direct object is rare and I'm not sure whether it's correct.

Comment: But the Collins quotation does not use _encroach_ transitively. I am prepared to assert that transiive _encroach_ is not (currently) English.

Comment: @ColinFine I've noted it in the last paragraph that the transitive use might be wrong - but the OP's question was whether you can use *encroach (upon)* to refer to a person rather than their eg. personal space, which I don't find too much of an issue with.